# Unable to run java file from command like Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot execute Java program: UnsupportedClassVersionError](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84491/cannot-execute-java-program-unsupportedclassversionerror)

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu and Im looking to run Java code from the command line. Ive checked that path as well. The interesting thing is the code compiles but fails to run

ie.

```
user@ubuntu:~/py-scripts$ javac Main.java' works well.
```

but when I do .

```
`user@ubuntu:~/py-scripts$ java Main
```

I get  the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
 Could not find the main class: Main. Program will exit.'
```

Comment: What version of Java are you running?  Run "java -version" and see what you get.

Comment: can you post your Main.java

Comment: @tachyons ,@Kelley
Main.java
public class Main 
{ 
    public static void main (String[] args)  
   {  
       System.out.println ("Hello, world."); 
   } 
}  

and java version:OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: whats the result of ls ?

Comment: verify that Main.class exit in your directory ,else change your directory to home folder

Comment: @tachyons, ls returns


countMerge.java  Hello.py  **Main.class**  Main.java  SplitString.py

Comment: @Lekensteyn, tried javac -version and java version , here's what I get

vivek@ubuntu:~/py-scripts$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_147
vivek@ubuntu:~/py-scripts$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: @KodeSeeker See my answer in the duplicate question.

Comment: @Lekensteyn, how do I uninstall openjdk-7?

Comment: The package is `openjdk-7-jdk`, the command for removal is `sudo apt-get remove openjdk-7-jdk`

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple versions of the JRE/JDK installed (e.g. versions 6 and 7), you should make sure that the JRE you're running (using `java`) uses a version that is class-compatible with what you've used to compile the class (e.g. JRE 7 for classes compiled with JDK 6 or 7, but not JRE 6 for classes compiled with JDK 7).

You can keep multiple versions installed and choose which one is used by `java` and `javac` using `update-alternatives --config java` and `update-alternatives --config javac` (as [documented here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java#Choosing_the_default_Java_to_use)).